# Firefox Awesomebar first character?

Tags: firefox, awesomebar, special-characters

In the Firefox (3.6.6) [Awesomebar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox_3#Frontend_changes):

```
? grape
```

searches Google* for "grape".

```
! grape
```

shows the "I'm Feeling Lucky" Google page for "grape".

With what other "special" characters can I start the Firefox address bar, and what are their functions?

Comment: [S] [Down] [Enter] goes to superuser.com.  (Or is that just for me?)

Comment: Weird mine goes to sailormoon.com - Must be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [on the internets](http://lifehacker.com/5063481/firefox-31-adds-keyword-filters-to-the-awesomebar):

> You can restrict the search to your history by typing ^, or bookmarks with *, or tagged pages with +. To make what you’ve typed match only in the URL type @, and for title/tags only use #.

Answer (score 2):

Not *quite* built in actions - but if you add extra search engines to the search box and then assign them keywords you can *sort of* build your own special actions.

For example I just have to type in `su firefox` and hit enter to do a search here on SuperUser for `firefox`. I can also just use `su` to come straight here without searching.

Here's a few more examples that I use regularly(ish):

- `so` (StackOverflow)
- `g` (google)
- `wiki` (Wikipedia)
- `wikid` (Wikitonary)
- `wolf` (Wolfram Alpha)

Basically hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (whichever needed).
Type in the short code from the list and (optionally for *some* sites) what you want to search for.
Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Job done.

Unfortunately, I frequently find myself writing them in to the address bar of IE when at work....

Comment: Wish I'd known about this earlier, I've been using the "site" modifier (eg site:superuser.com) for ages now!